# Lotus Notes / highlight specific sender in the common mailbox

Tags: formatting, lotus-notes, mail-sender

I use Lotus Notes 8.5.3 and I have one common mailbox which is used by many people. When we send emails we always CC our mailbox and what we see in the "Who" field is the mailbox name. But in the details of each email I can find that it was sent for example by me.

Now the question is - can I somehow highlight emails in the common mailbox sent by myself?

Simple *File/Preferences/Mail/Sender Colors* I think does't help...

Answer (score 1):

You can easily highlight a sender on Lotus Notes. Here is how.

- First, copy the name in Notes format of the person you want to highlight - Example:  joe smoke/costa mesa/XYZ or whatever your company uses.

  - Go to the Notes icon (next to the Apple logo if you use a Mac).
  - Select Preferences.
  - Click on Mail (It is a small pull down with a little arrow).
  - Now, select Access Delegation.
  - Now, select MAIL(it is the first tab on the left....and a little hard to see as it is on small letters.
  - Then select SENDER COLORS.  It is located words the right and it is  a little hard to see.
  - Now, paste the name of the sender you want to highlight and select the color on the right and side.  You can also write but make sure to write it without mistakes and on the correct Notes format.
  - Press OK at the bottom of the screen to save.
  - Now, re-start Notes for the changes to take effect.

After re-starting Notes, you will see the name of the sender highlighted in the color you picked.  If it does not show highlighted, you probably made a mistake writing the name of the person.  Just do it again.

Best of luck and have a Super Fantastic day!

NOTE:  This process works for most versions on Notes.  When writing this, I was using Notes version 10.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the folder `($Inbox)` in Domino Designer.

Insert a new hidden column at the beginning and enable "Use value as color" property.

Then enter a formula for the column:

```
red := 255:0:0;
blue := 0:0:255;

@If(
    @Contains ( From ; "Quora Digest" ) ;
        blue;
    @Contains ( From ; "Mario Rossi" );
        red;
    ""
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't install any software on the company PC so I guess I can't test it. But thanks for the tip, Roman.

Answer (score 0):

You could even manage the changes w/o installing software like Designer Client - but that won't help because the suggested solution (by DonAndreas) modifying the Inbox Folder does exactly the same thing like File/Preferences/Mail/Sender Colors (in a much more worse way).

Any modification in design or preferences like this will result in a visible change to all users who are working in this mailbox! All users would see YOUR mails in another color but never their own mails like this.

What you really need is a change where "me" means not only you rather each users name by itself. So Jon Doe should see mails from Jon Doe in another color while Jane Doe sees her own mails in another color but Jon's mails in standard color.

The next problem is the difference beetween sender (from) and sent by (principal) - any previous discussed change would only affect 'from' but never 'principal' - which you need to accomplish your needs.

What could help is a feature called "private on first use" which creates automatically a slightly different (i.e. uses "me" in a dynamic way like @UserName) view for each user. BUT: the Inbox must not exist in multiple copies because the router would only deliver mails to the first one it sees and all others will stay empty. Moving mails between (each users) Inbox and other folders would only affect the users copy of the original Inbox - not visible in the other Inboxes ;) You don't want that 'solution'.

So there is no simple solution as long as we speak about the original Inbox or folders in general.